# How do I return a Vector java

Tags: java, function, vector

How do I return a vector in a java function. I want to unserialize a vector loaded from a file and return in a function but I get errors. This is what code I currently have.

```
    private static Vector<Countries> loadOB(String sFname) throws ClassNotFoundException, IOException {
        ObjectInputStream oStream = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(sFname));
        Object object = oStream.readObject();
        oStream.close();
        return object;
    }
```

Comment: It works with your solution under.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to cast the object that you read from the file to Vector:

```
private static Vector<Countries> loadOB(String sFname) throws ClassNotFoundException, IOException {
        ObjectInputStream oStream = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(sFname));
        try{
          Object object = oStream.readObject();
          if (object instanceof Vector)
              return (Vector<Countries>) object;
          throw new IllegalArgumentException("not a Vector in "+sFname);
        }finally{
           oStream.close();
        }
     }
```

Note that you cannot check if it is really a Vector of Countries (short of checking the contents one by one).

Answer (score 1):

This is a wild guess, but try `return (Vector<Countries>) object;`